# Firefox, Chrome integration help under Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome

I just downloaded Google Chrome for Linux, but it isn't completed enough to use for everything. So I want to be able to use both Firefox, and Chrome, and I want to, for example, keep my bookmarks in sync.

I will probably run both of them at the same time, so I would appreciate anything that would be helpful in that situation. For example dragging a link from one to the other.

---

What hints can you offer me?

*( I can create a machine local website, if that helps )*

Answer (score 3):

Since Chrome doesn't have the addon ability of Firefox, you have to make do with online solutions.

- Bookmarks: [Delicious](http://delicious.com/) or [XMarks](http://www.foxmarks.com/) - neither of these have the nice integration with Chrome that they do with Firefox, but you will be able to access your bookmarks from either browser.
- Passwords: [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) - The integration is a bit nicer with Firefox due to the addon, but the Lastpass bookmarklets are serviceable. Obviously you need to make sure you trust them to store your passwords securely, however the service works quite nicely.

Comment: I currently use Password Maker for passwords.

Comment: I have just started experimenting with the bookmark services you suggested.